# Some server configuration thats not allowing certain AJAX requests

Tags: apache-2.2

I have two apache web servers. I installed FengOffice on both the servers.
On one server it works perfectly fine.

On the other no AJAX request work in Chrome and FF but it works in IE.

Why would this happen?

Comment: Are you going to tell us something useful or do you just want us to take a guess?

Comment: I am just as clueless as you are. Both servers are running plain vanilla installation of Apache and PHP. What more information do you want ? Be specific.

Comment: Maybe something like, the OS you're running? The versions of all relevant software? Any firewalls involved?

Comment: for starters we need to know what OS, what is in the relevant logs, have you compared the relevant config files on both servers, what have you checked so far.

Comment: Ubuntu 10. with the plain default Apache configs.

Answer (score 2):

Use something like Fiddler to capture what the browser sees when using one server versus the other. Also, look in the Apache logs to see what's different from the server perspective.